# How to iterate through spark cogroup values

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

```
1) for Categories

twitter handle , categories , sub_categories 

handle        ,  Products ,    MakeUp 
handle        ,  Health,     MakeUp
handle2        , Services ,     Face
handle3         , Marketing ,    Soap

JavaPairRDD<String ,Category> categoryPairRDD

2) For Twitter 

Twitter handle , twitter_post , twitter_likes 

 handle                "Iphone"              , 10 
 handle2               "Samsung"                 ,20


JavaPairRDD<String ,Twitter>  twitterPairRDD


JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Ontologies>, Iterable<Twitter>>> grouped = categoryPairRDD
           .cogroup(twitterPairRDD);
```

How should I iterate the cogroup values such that If for a Key if the object is found print the values, else
print null values

i.e. In my categoryPairRDD handle3 is present but its absent in twitterRDD so out put for key handle3 should be

```
handle3 , Marketing , Soap , null , null
```

Final out put should be

```
handle , Products , Makeup  , Iphone , 10
handle , Health , Makeup ,  , Iphone, 10 
handle2 , Services , Face , Samsung , 20
handle3  , Marketing, Soap ,  null , null
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get a solution

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Ontologies, Optional<twitterPairRDD>>> left =  ontologiesPair.leftOuterJoin(twitterPairRDD);

    left.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String,Tuple2<Ontologies,Optional<Twitter>>>>() {

        @Override
        public void call(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Ontologies, Optional<Instagram>>> arg0) throws Exception {
            try{
                 Optional<Twitter> tweet = arg0._2._2();
                 //print values from tuple ie arg0._2._1() and tweet    object      
              }   
               catch(Exception e){
                Twitter tweet = new Twitter("",-1);
               //Print values from arg0._2._1() and empty tweet object
            }
```

But still I would like to know any answer using co-group